# Travel to Ambikapur, Chhattisgarh

Tags: trains, india, south-india

What is the easiest way to travel from large Southern cities (Hyderabad, Mangaluru, Bengaluru, Vijayawada, Visakhapatnam, Chennai) in India to Ambikapur, Chhattisgarh?

Easiest defined as not having to wait more than two hours in between cities and completed in one 24-hour span.

Comment: What does "easiest" mean: fastest, or cheapest, or fewest changes, or something else? People value different things, and what is "easiest" to you may well be "not so easy" for someone else. What place is "Southern cities in India" ?

Comment: Edited to define southern cities in India and clarify what 'easy' means.

Comment: Still unclear to me. Do you mean from Hyderabad to Amibkapur, and from Mengaluru to Ambikapur, etc, or Hyderabed to Mengaluru etc and then to Ambikapur? We do question-and-answer here, but the site expects one question per post, not multiple segments or travel planning.

Comment: Rome2Rio says you’ll be pretty hard pressed on the 24 hour limit for, for example, Hyderabad to Ambikapur with anything other than flying. So… take a flight to a nearby airport and then a taxi…!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a flight to Ranchi / Raipur.

From Raipur, Ambikapur is a 6 hour drive away. From Ranchi, it's even closer.

You could try Jharsuguda too.

[image]

[image]

Other options are impractical, given the 24-hour time frame. You can't get to even Mumbai in this time by any way other than flying.

Comment: The origin airport is Hyderabad here. Chennai and BLR have flights (direct) to the places mentioned above.